How to correctly generate .d.ts files for library package
I'm working on an JavaScript NPM library package and trying to get typescript to generate a .d.ts file from the jsdocs embedded in the file.
Let's say I have the following three files:
index.js, the main entry point into library:
export * from "./foo.js";
export * from "./bar.js";

foo.js:
/** This is the foo function */
export function foo()
{
}

and bar.js:
/** This is the bar function */
export function bar()
{
}

I then run tsc with config like so:
{
    "include": [
        "index.js",
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "outFile": "index.d.ts",
        "declarationMap": true,
    }
}

and I get an index.ts.d with this:
declare module "foo" {
    /** This is the foo function */
    export function foo(): void;
}
declare module "bar" {
    /** This is the bar function */
    export function bar(): void;
}
declare module "index" {
    export * from "foo";
    export * from "bar";
}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map

But this doesn't work as expected with the intellisense in VSCode.  For example, when adding imports, VS Code adds:
import { foo } from "foo";

instead of
import { foo } from "@myscope/mylib";

So what I'm hoping for is a way for tsc to generate something like this:
declare module "@myscope/mylib" {
    /** This is the foo function */
    export function foo(): void;

    /** This is the bar function */
    export function bar(): void;
}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map

What am I missing?  Is there some way to get tsc to generate a .d.ts file where the entire library is considered a single module, with the scoped package name that I want?

This is more about configuring aname and exports in your package.json file than generating types.

@morganney Yes I realize this. The above is just sample code I was using to experiment with the .d.ts file generation and to explain the issue.  My real lib has the full package.json file.

First, you need to modify the configuration as follows:

tsconfig.json

{
  "include": ["index.js"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  }
}

This code will generate all type definitions into the types folder. At this point, if you only want your library to provide type hints, you can reference types/index.d.ts.
If your requirement is to generate a single .d.ts file containing the types of the entire library, I'm afraid to say that TypeScript itself does not support this capability. We need the support of a bundler, such as rollup.
First, install the necessary libraries:
pnpm add -D rollup rollup-plugin-dts

Then, you can use this configuration file:

rollup.config.js

import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

export default {
  input: "./types/index.d.ts", 
  output: {
    file: "./dist/index.d.ts",
    format: "es",
  },
  plugins: [dts()],
};

Next, run the command:
tsc && npx rollup -c

 Now you have a single file containing the complete type:


This is pretty close but the "dts" plugin seems to drop the source mapping so "go to definition" in VSCode jumps to the .d.ts file instead of the original .js file.

I have written a tool that integrates all the packaging steps in this series:
https://github.com/unbuilderjs/undts
Currently, undts not only supports the bundle of d.ts files, but also has built-in support for generating d.ts for four types of files: vue/svelte/astro/vue vine, and directly packages them together!
I have tried my best to make it easy to use like tsup and @antfu/eslint config. Its configuration is extremely simple and clear, just install it and use it directly!
pnpm i undts

